# StringBuilder and string.IsIntern method

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Anybody can explain, why this code return abc, True?

```
        var str1 = "abc";
        var str2 = "";

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("a");
        builder.Append("b");
        builder.Append("c");


        str2 = builder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(str2));
        Console.WriteLine(str1.Equals(str2));
```

I look StringBuilder.ToString() method with reflector but can't find any using of string.Intern in it.

I use Net Framework 4.5

Comment: What is the output which you are expecting?

Comment: see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't understand why you expect that they are not equal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the question makes more sense if you assume the OP intended to check for reference equality, i.e. `ReferenceEquals`, not `Equals`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: i would have understood if OP had used `==` since it's a commmon misunderstanding that `==` just compares references. However, i agree that this might have been his intention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IsInterned` returns a non-`null` value because you are asking:

> "is there an interned value matching this sequence? if so, give me the interned value"

Yes, there is an interned value, because string literals via `ldstr` are interned, and the string literal `"abc"` is used in that method (meaning: it will have been interned during the JIT of that method).

The `Equals` returning true is not interesting: try `ReferenceEquals` and you see `false`. They are different string instances; meaning: the value from the builder is **not** the same instance as the interned literal. This confirms what you are saying: `StringBuilder` does not automatically check the interning pool.

Perhaps more interesting is to add:

```
var str3 = string.IsInterned(str2);
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(str3, str1));
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(str3, str2));
```

which reports:

```
True
False
```

meaning: the interned string is the same string as the string literal; the string from the builder is unrelated.